# Android WebView link respond only on double click after setting onTouch listener to it

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I created A WebView , and in my WebView I have a button, which change the page in the WebView when it clicked. Also I set a touch listener on the WebView. But after setting a touch listener the button respond only on QUICK double click. I mean you should click two times with no continuously interval between clicks. Here is my code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment implements SolutionHandler {
        private static final String SAVE_DASHBOARD_PAGE = "saveDashboardPage";
        private static final String SAVE_DASHBOARD_WEB_STATE = "saveDashboardWebState";


    private static final String DASHBOARD_URL = "https://api.myApp.com/api/dashboard/";
    private static final String LOGOUT_URL = "myapp://logout/";
    private static final String SOLUTION_URL = "mytapp://solution/open?solution_id";
    private static final String MY_APP = "myapp://";


        private View dashboardView;
        private WebView dashboardWebView;

        private String currentUrl;
        private User user;

        private LoadingDialog loadingDialog;

        private Bundle webState;

        private int supportUrlAcessCount = 0;

        public DashboardFragment() {
             setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            dashboardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

            user = User.sharedUser(getActivity());

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                currentUrl = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_DASHBOARD_PAGE);
                webState = savedInstanceState.getBundle(SAVE_DASHBOARD_WEB_STATE);
            }

            if (currentUrl == null || currentUrl.length() == 0) {
                currentUrl = DASHBOARD_URL + user.hash();
            }

            loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(getActivity(), R.string.loading_dashboard, R.string.icon_arrows_cw, true);
            WebChromeClient webClient = new WebChromeClient();

            if (dashboardWebView == null) {
                dashboardWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
                dashboardWebView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                dashboardWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                dashboardWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                dashboardWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                dashboardWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
                dashboardWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                dashboardWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    //          dashboardWebView.setOnTouchListener(webViewTouchListener);

                dashboardWebView.setWebChromeClient(webClient);
                dashboardWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        if (url.startsWith(DASHBOARD_URL)) {
                            view.clearHistory();
                            loadingDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        if (url != null && url.startsWith(OHITAPP)) {
                            if (url.startsWith(SOLUTION_URL)) {
                                loadingDialog.setStringResource(R.string.loading_solution);
                                loadingDialog.show();

                                Locker.lock(getActivity());

                                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
                                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

                                String solutionId = "";

                                if (matcher.find()) {
                                    solutionId = matcher.group();
                                }

                                APITalker.sharedTalker().getSolution(user.hash(), Integer.valueOf(solutionId), false,
                                        APITalker.CALL_TYPES.CALL_TYPE_DEEP_LINK, DashboardFragment.this);
                            } else if (url.startsWith(LOGOUT_URL)) {
                                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                                ErrorHelper.showError(TalkersConstants.HASH_INVALID, (SuperActivity) getActivity());
                            }

                            return true;
                        } else if (url.startsWith("http://support")) {
                            supportUrlAcessCount++;
                            if (supportUrlAcessCount == 2) {
                                ((MenuActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(6, false, false, false, null, null);

                                return true;
                            }

                            return false;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                        showNoInternetError();
                    }
                });

                if (webState == null) {
                    if (CheckConnectionHelper.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
                        loadingDialog.show();
                        dashboardWebView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
                    } else {
                        ErrorHelper.showError(TalkersConstants.JUST_FAILURE, (SuperActivity) getActivity());
                        dashboardWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                    }


                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    dashboardWebView.restoreState(webState);
                }
            } else {
                if (webState == null) {
                    loadingDialog.show();
                    dashboardWebView.loadUrl(currentUrl);

                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    dashboardWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    dashboardWebView.restoreState(webState);
                }
            }

            LinearLayout dashboardContainer = (LinearLayout) dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_container);
            dashboardContainer.addView(dashboardWebView);

            getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver()
                    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            dashboardView.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });

    //      SuperActivity.savedLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            return dashboardView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            LinearLayout dashboardContainer = (LinearLayout) dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_container);
            dashboardContainer.removeView(dashboardWebView);

            super.onDestroyView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString(SAVE_DASHBOARD_PAGE, getCurrentPage());
            outState.putBundle(SAVE_DASHBOARD_WEB_STATE, getCurrentWebViewState());

            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        public String getCurrentPage() {
            return dashboardWebView.getUrl();
        }

        public Bundle getCurrentWebViewState() {
            Bundle outState = new Bundle();
            dashboardWebView.saveState(outState);

            return outState;
        }

        @Override
        public void solutionSuccess(int solutionId, boolean isVoice, String title, String html, String speech) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();

            Solution solution = new Solution(solutionId, title);

            ArrayList<Solution> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
            solutions.add(solution);

            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.flip_right_in, R.anim.flip_right_out);
            Intent solutionIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SolutionActivity.class);
            solutionIntent.putExtra(SolutionActivity.ACCESS_METHOD_EXTRA, APITalker.ACCESS_METHODS.ACCESS_METHOD_DEEPLINKSOLUTION);
            solutionIntent.putExtra(SolutionActivity.HTML_EXTRA, html);
            solutionIntent.putExtra(SolutionActivity.SPEECH_EXTRA, speech);
            solutionIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(SolutionActivity.SOLUTIONS_EXTRA, solutions);
            solutionIntent.putExtra(SolutionActivity.POSITION_EXTRA, 0);
            startActivityForResult(solutionIntent, SolutionActivity.REQUEST_CODE, options.toBundle());

            Locker.unlock(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public void solutionFailure(String error) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();

            if (error.equals(TalkersConstants.HASH_INVALID)) {
                ((MenuActivity) getActivity()).logout(null);
            }

            ErrorHelper.showError(error, (SuperActivity) getActivity());

            Locker.unlock(getActivity());
        }

        public boolean navigatesBack() {
            if (dashboardWebView != null && dashboardWebView.canGoBack()) {
                dashboardWebView.goBack();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void showNoInternetError() {
            loadingDialog.dismiss();
            ErrorHelper.showError(TalkersConstants.JUST_FAILURE, (SuperActivity) getActivity());
            dashboardWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        }

        public void reloadWebView() {
            if (dashboardWebView.getUrl() == null
                    || dashboardWebView.getUrl().isEmpty()
                    || dashboardWebView.getUrl().equals("about:blank")) {
                dashboardWebView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
            }
        }

        OnTouchListener webViewTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - SuperActivity.savedLastClickTime < 2000) {
                    Log.d("I AM IN A FALSE", "FALSE");
                    return false;
                }

                SuperActivity.savedLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d("I AM IN A TOUCH LISTENER", "TOUCH LISTENER");
                view.performClick();
                return true;
            }
        };




    }
```

This is DashboardFragment code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** I also wrote the logs to determine onTouch listener behavior. Post edited code and logs

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - SuperActivity.savedLastClickTime < 2000) {
                Log.d("I AM IN A FALSE", "FALSE");
                return false;
            }

            SuperActivity.savedLastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("I AM IN A TOUCH LISTENER", "TOUCH LISTENER");
            view.performClick();
            return true;
        }
    };
```

And the Logs

```
11-26 15:01:21.747: D/I AM IN A TOUCH LISTENER(16231): TOUCH LISTENER
11-26 15:01:21.817: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:21.837: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:36.747: D/I AM IN A TOUCH LISTENER(16231): TOUCH LISTENER
11-26 15:01:36.837: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:36.847: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:39.387: E/NMSP(16231): [bz] Session Idle for too long, longer than [50] (initiated from XMode.parseBcp)
11-26 15:01:39.597: E/NMSP(16231): [bz] XMode.parseXModeMsg() unknown protocol: 0
11-26 15:01:39.597: I/SpeechKit(16231): Disconnected
11-26 15:01:42.367: D/I AM IN A TOUCH LISTENER(16231): TOUCH LISTENER
11-26 15:01:42.407: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:42.457: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:42.537: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:49.407: D/I AM IN A TOUCH LISTENER(16231): TOUCH LISTENER
11-26 15:01:49.457: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:49.527: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
11-26 15:01:49.597: D/I AM IN A FALSE(16231): FALSE
```

So, on each click app entered touch listener 3 times:  first time just into touch listener, and 2, 3 times in a "false" part of it. But why?

Comment: please post your layout

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. But as You see it's quite simple. :)

Comment: your are using fragment, then try it with clickable="true" in your layout

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, Nas

Comment: Here where you inflate the "dashboardView" view?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question. I haven't posted all the code, only parts where there is WebView present.

Comment: But I think, my problem is that I use System.currentTimeMillis() to change the click behavior.

Comment: your are doing too much operation in oncreateview it has chances to skip ontouch listner in onCreateview and try it placing those thing in onActivityCreated method declare the ontouchlistener on the same method.

Comment: Please post your complete code. so that we can help more. Otherwise its hard to find the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96256/discussion-between-victor-and-nas).